# How to create a date in excel with HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel

In one cell I have 1/20/2015 and in another cell I have 20:56:33.

How can I create a date that is 1/20/2015 20:56:33?

Thank you

Comment: You can google it if you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the date in A1 and the time in B1, the answer in C1 is as simple as

`=A1+B1`

Then format C1 to show date and time with seconds: right click on C1, Format Cells > Number > Custom, and enter

```
m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss
```

Comment: Just format the cell as Date-Time. There is an option default in Excel for this

Answer (score 0):

Just concat both columns in one. =A1+A2

Press crtl + 1 in your cell, its will open the properties of cell, go to first tab, select data type and set the mask.

its easier...